# Installing Another Virtual machine on a virtual machine using oracle linux 5.8

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am implementing Oracle RAC using 11.2. For shared disc option and low cost, we are planning to use Virtual Machines. I have installed one virtual machine (PARENT) Specifications: Oracle Linux 5.8 (64 bit) RAM 16GB HDD 90GB CPU 1

After installing VM, I tried to install another VM (CHILD) using Oracle Virtual Box. Specification for CHILD vm Oracle Linux 5.8 (32 bit) [ as Oracle VM doesnt give a 64 bit option while installing Child virtual machine] RAM 2GB HDD 50GB CPU 1

It's giving error

```
Starting udev:................................[Failed]
```

Questions:

What is the possible the possible reason?

I want to use Oracle RAC using Linux 5.8. We have don't have other option than Linux. What is the procedure which I need to follow.

When I am installing Oracle VM Box on 64 bit machine. The option for 64 bit child machine is not available at the time of creating virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Nested virtual machines are not supported in VirtualBox. 64 bit options don't show up because they require hardware virtualization, which is not available in virtual machines.

References:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20589

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032